# Numba - nopython mode slower than object mode?

Tags: python, numba

First using Numba here. I read that nopython mode should produce faster code but this:

```
@jit(float64[:](int64[:], int64, float64), nopython=True)
def epsilon_bound(l, k, delta):
    return l/k+np.sqrt(np.log(1/delta))*np.sqrt(1/(2*k))

@jit(float64(float64, int64, float64), nopython=False)
def sim_bin(epsilon, sims, delta):
    k=10000
    s = np.random.binomial(k, epsilon, size=(sims,))
    print(nb.typeof(s))
    bound = epsilon_bound(s, k, delta)
    violations = np.greater(epsilon, bound)
    return np.sum(violations)/float(sims)

%%time
a = sim_bin(0.1, 1_000_000, 0.1)
```

is running much faster:

```
array(int64, 1d, C)
CPU times: user 66.7 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 66.7 ms
Wall time: 65.7 ms
```

than this:

```
@jit(float64[:](int64[:], int64, float64), nopython=True)
def epsilon_bound(l, k, delta):
    return l/k+np.sqrt(np.log(1/delta))*np.sqrt(1/(2*k))

@jit(float64(float64, int64, float64), nopython=True)
def sim_bin(epsilon, sims, delta):
    k=10000
    s = np.random.binomial(k, epsilon, size=(sims,))
    #print(nb.typeof(s))
    bound = epsilon_bound(s, k, delta)
    violations = np.greater(epsilon, bound)
    return np.sum(violations)/float(sims)

CPU times: user 4.94 s, sys: 8.02 ms, total: 4.95 s
Wall time: 4.93 s
```

Running sim_bin.inspect_types() shows that the first option is using all pyobjects while the second option is correctly inferring all the types. According to the documentation (http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.31.0/glossary.html#term-nopython-mode) nopython mode should produce faster code.
Does anyone know what is going on? There must be a good reason but I am new at using Numba. Is it because I am mostly using vectorized numpy functions?

Thanks!!

Comment: When I run these two pieces of code, I see no performance difference. In general though, you want to disregard the time of the first run of a numba jitted function since that includes the jitting time (so use `%timeit` instead of `%time`).

Comment: @JoshAdel By providing signatures you pre-compile the function so the compile run shouldn't be necessary. I can't see a time difference between these calls but I definetly can see a time difference between jitted `np.random.binomial` and the unjitted one.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to include which version of python and numba I was using. It's python 3.6, numba 0.31, numpy 1.12 on linux. I'll check whether this regression has been fixed. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One major bottleneck of the function (at least with numba 0.31, windows 10) seems to be the `np.random.binomial`-call. When I test it:

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def nbbinom():
    return np.random.binomial(10000, 0.1, size=(1000000,))

nbbinom() # warmup
%timeit nbbinom()
# 1 loop, best of 3: 2.45 s per loop
%timeit np.random.binomial(10000, 0.1, size=(1000000,))
# 10 loops, best of 3: 23.1 ms per loop
```

However it could be that this depends on the numba version. Numba (unfortunatly) often suffers from performance regressions that (fortunatly) are fixed fast. Probably it only needs an issue on their bug tracker (if it's not already fixed).

But even then your code contains a lot of vectorized operations. You won't get much of a speedboost with numba if you use vectorized operations. As a rule of thumb: **If you already can do it with numpy without using python loops you don't need numba** (there are exceptions. For example: I found that numba is definetly faster for small arrays where the numpy-ufuncs have significant overhead).

Another thing is that creating the random-array takes much longer (in numpy and numba) than the actual operation:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def epsilon_bound1(l, k, delta):
    return l/k+np.sqrt(np.log(1/delta))*np.sqrt(1/(2*k))

def epsilon_bound2(l, k, delta):
    return l/k+np.sqrt(np.log(1/delta))*np.sqrt(1/(2*k))

def sim_bin(s, k, epsilon, sims, delta, func):
    bound = func(s, k, delta)
    violations = np.greater(epsilon, bound)
    return np.sum(violations)/float(sims)

epsilon = 0.1
sims = 1000000
delta = 0.1
k=10000
s = np.random.binomial(k, epsilon, size=(sims,))
%timeit np.random.binomial(k, epsilon, size=(sims,))
# 1 loop, best of 3: 232 ms per loop

sim_bin(s, k, 0.1, 1000000, 0.1, epsilon_bound1)  # warmup
%timeit sim_bin(s, k, 0.1, 1000000, 0.1, epsilon_bound1)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 28.5 ms per loop
%timeit sim_bin(s, k, 0.1, 1000000, 0.1, epsilon_bound2)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 37.6 ms per loop
```

So when you benchmark `sim_bin` you actually only benchmark the call to `np.random.binomial`, either the relativly fast numpy one or the (currently) quite slow numba implementation.

Comment: thanks a lot! I didn't know numba reimplemented random.binomial. I suspected I wouldn't get much of a speedup but I was very dissapointed when I saw it to run slower. Now that I know that it should not happen I'll post it as a bug.

Comment: I tried to use vectorize instead of jit on epsilon_bound but results were 50% slower. Would you say these performance differences are predictable (once one understands what's going on behind the curtains) or is it a matter of trial and error?

Comment: I tested your nbbinom comparison in numba 0.26 and 0.25  and the performance was slower than the random.binomial as you saw in 0.31. I am guessing it's not a regression then, simply a slower implementation. I also tried v0.21 and v0.23 but it wouldn't run.

Comment: @Luk17 Regarding the predictability: It's unlikely that numba can do much better than numpy. Simply because if it could be faster (except for parallel executions) then numpy would _probably_ also use the faster way. However when you got stuck with numpy and try to use python-loops then probably should use cython/numba. However one can't predict something like `np.random.binomial`, that's an unexpected poor-performance function. :)